# Change behavior of class with template paramenetrs

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I would like to write a class which have two template parameter where both of them is a boolean. Both of them can enable different extra functionalities if they are set to true.
I would like to acheave something like this (this is not working):

```
template<bool A, bool B>
class foo {
private:
    int v1;
#if A
    int v2;
#endif

public:
    void f1() {}
#if B
    void f2() {}
#endif
    int f3() {
        #if A
            return v2;
        #else
            return v1;
        #endif
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this goal without any perforamnce penalty?

Comment: How should I use specialization, to avoid writing 4 different classes for the 4 different cases without duplicating the code used in more than one case?

Comment: With specialization, CRTP, and refactoring then.

Comment: You can also specialize the members without having to specialize the whole class.

Comment: The real question is what real problem you're trying to solve by having a template that changes its public API based on the template parameters?

Comment: I want to implement some complex data structure, where I want to make it possible to disable some functionality (what require to store and manipulate additional data) to increase the speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRTP, specialization, and refactoring:

```
template<typename D, bool A>
struct foo_A
{
public:
  D const* self() const {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<foo_A<D,A>, D>::value, "CRTP failure" );
    return static_cast<D const*>(this);
  }
  D* self() {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<foo_A<D,A>, D>::value, "CRTP failure" );
    return static_cast<D*>(this);
  }
  void f3() {
    return self()->v2;
  }
};
template<typename D>
struct foo_A<D, true>
{
private:
  int v2;
public:
  D const* self() const {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<foo_A<D,A>, D>::value, "CRTP failure" );
    return static_cast<D const*>(this);
  }
  D* self() {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<foo_A<D,A>, D>::value, "CRTP failure" );
    return static_cast<D*>(this);
  }
  void f3() {
    return self()->v1;
  }
};

template<typename D, bool B> struct foo_B {};
template<typename D>
struct foo_B<D,true> {
  void f2() {}
};

template<bool A, bool B>
class foo:
  foo_A<foo<A,B>,A>,
  foo_B<foo<A,B>,B>
{
private:
  int v1;

public:
  void f1() {}
};
```

CRTP lets your helper classes have static compile time access to the contents of your class, and even the other helper classes.

Specialization in the helper classes, with proper refactoring, gives you nice tight conditions that aren't growing exponentially.  You can even do some common logic in your derived class, and access these values in each specialization.

Comment: Ah, glad someone posted this.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid combinatorial explosion by making one base template per dimension. For example, for your code:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, bool> struct impl_foo
    {
        int f3()
        {
            return static_cast<T*>(this)->v1;
        }
    };

    template <typename T> struct impl_foo<T, true>
    {
        int v2;

        int f3()
        {
            return v2;
        }
    };

    template <bool> struct impl_bar { };

    template <> struct impl_foo<true>
    {
        void f2();
    };
}

template <bool A, bool B>
struct MyClass : detail::impl_foo<MyClass, A>, detail::impl_foo<B>
{
    int v1;
}
```

For the `impl_foo` mixin we use the recurring template pattern to access elements of the main class from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool A, bool B>
class foo;

template<bool B>
class foo<true, B> {
    private:
    int v1;
    int v2;

public:
    void f1() {std::cout << "A\n";}

    int f3() {
        return v2;
    }
};

template<bool A>
class foo<A, true> {
private:
    int v1;

public:
    void f1() {std::cout << "B\n";}
    void f2() {}

    int f3() {
        return v1;
    }
};

template<>
class foo<true, true> {
private:
    int v1;
    int v2;

public:
    void f1() {std::cout << "AB\n";}
    void f2() {}

    int f3() {
        return v2;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo<true, false> a;
    foo<false, true> b;
    foo<true, true> ab;

    a.f1();
    b.f1();
    ab.f1();
}
```

This prints:

> A
>   B
>   AB

Comment: If it is possible, I want to avoid writing 4 different classes with a lot of duplicated code.
(Now I have only 2 parameter, but what happens, if next time, I have 4. Than writing 16 very similar classes is absolutely silly.)

Comment: @SqrtPi, Yes, it should be possible. This way works, but it can be a lot longer.